# ErrorException array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array (View: C:\wamp64\www\MYPROJECT\resources\views\news\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Estoy trando de mostrar los elementos de una base de datos en Laravel y me sale este error

```
ErrorException array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array (View: C:\wamp64\www\MYPROJECT\resources\views\news\index.blade.php)
```

No encontre `services.json` y ya  hice `composer update`

La vista esta recibiendo los datos por que los imprimí con `dd('$variable')` y si salen, pero de alguna manera se daña cuando pongo la tabla:

```
@extends('layout.master')

@section('content')

<h1>News List</h1>
<p class="lead">Here's a list of all your tasks. <a href="http://localhost:8000/news/create">Add a new one?</a></p>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Article</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th width="280px">Options</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach($news as $info)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$info->title }}</td>
            <td>{{$info->article}}</td>
            <td>{{$info->image}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ view('news.show', $info->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">View Task</a>
        <a href="{{ view('news.edit', $info->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Task</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>

@endsection
```

Solo quitando esa parte desaparece el error, pero necesito listar lo guardado en la base de datos.

Comment: No me suena que `view()` este pensado para usar en ese contexto,  ya que retorna una vista no una url, en su lugar deberías usar `route()` o `url()` revisa los helpers: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-url

Comment: Era eso, Muchas Gracias!

Comment: te he añadido la respuesta para que la marques como aceptada si lo consideras oportuno. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `view()` en laravel es un helper global para retornar una de las vistas almacenadas en `resources/views/`

Sí lo que buscamos es obtener la url de una ruta deberiamos utilizar uno de los siguientes helpers:

### action()

```
$url = action('AlgunController@metodo', $parametros);
```

`action()` retorna una url para un método de un controlador.

### route()

```
$url = route('alias.ruta', $parametros);
```

`route()` retorna una url a partir del alias dado a una ruta.

### url()

```
$url = url('foo/bar', $parametros = [], $secure = null);
```

`url()` retorna una url completa a partir de una ruta relativa.

### secure_url()

```
$url = secure_url('foo/bar', $parameters = []);
```

Igual que la anterior pero utilizando `https` por defecto.

---

Para archivos js, imágenes, etc... laravel también provee un par de helpers

### asset()

```
$url = asset('foto.jpg');
```

Retorna la url para el archivo `foto.jpg` ubicado en el directorio `public/asset/`

---

Documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#urls

---

Por lo tanto y partiendo de la información anterior. En lugar de utilizar

```
{{ view('news.edit', $info->id) }}
```

Deberías de utilizar

```
{{ route('news.edit', $info->id) }}
```